# Automorphism group of $r$ copies of an algebraic group $G$

Tags: group-theory, algebraic-groups

Let $G$ be an algebraic group over an algebraically closed field $F$ of characteristic 0. Let $r>0$ be an integer. I want to express the size of the automorphism group $Aut(G^r)$, where the automorphisms are in the category of algebraic groups over $F$, in terms of $Aut(G)$, which we assume to be finite. Here $G^r = G \times ... \times G$.

> Is the formula $\# Aut(G^r) = r! \cdot \# Aut(G)$ correct?

I think that the only way to get an automorphism of $G^r$ is to combine swapping factors ($r!$ ways to do so) with some automorphism of $G$, but I'm not completely sure about this.

Comment: Perhaps you need more assumptions on your group? For instance, if $G$ is abelian, then $(x,y)\mapsto (x,xy)$ is an automorphism of $G\times G$.

Comment: @Pierre-GuyPlamondon Good point! Do you know if any formula for computing the size of the group I'm interested in exists, by the way?

Comment: I suspect it depends heavily on $G$... if you have a specific example (or class of examples) in mind, it would be better to edit the question to make it narrower.